# QR Code Plugins Issue - Jeff

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, qr-code

I used a plugin to create A **QR Code** from a [plugin](http://code.google.com/p/qrcode-rails/) which says to use the below code in ruby page

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<%= qrcode('http://www.facebook.com/', 2, 3, 'my-qrcode') %>
```

I was expecting an image file , instead i got a table with lots of values in it. I tried a different ways to find a QRCode image generator and the only one seems to give an image is google charts, which i find not that interesting, I used them like

```
<%= image_tag("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chl=#{'http://www.facebook.com/'}&chs=120x120&choe=UTF-8", :size => "120x120")%>
```

Does anyone knows any other useful plugin that gives me the following output

- I need to see a QR code for a link (where the parameters of the link
  changes)
- When i click on a link below it, it should be able to download the
  QRCode image.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into [rqrcode](https://github.com/whomwah/rqrcode). It seems to do what you want.

There is an old example app [here](https://github.com/siuying/qrcode-rails)

Comment: Thanks Serabem wil lok into this, i attained what i want in another way by using googles api to generate the QR code as an image and if we right click on it we wud find an option to save as image <%=image_tag( "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chl=#{top_qr_url(@top.id)}&chs=180x180&choe=UTF-8", :size => "180x180" ,:id=>"top_promote",:topic=>@top.name) %>